# DDD using an ORM and a Active Directory Server for Persistence

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, orm, domain-model, persistence

With `Domain Driven Design` one would model out the domain. One would then use an `ORM` of some sort to take care of the persistence. Say you have a `Product` entity which has a `Name`, `SKU` and an `Owner`. This will be modelled and when a new `Product` gets created you need to pass in all 3 fields as parameters into the constructor.

The above will be persisted by Fluent NHibernate using a Postgresql Database.

The `Owner` of the product is of type `Account`. The `Account` is an entity which holds `ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Phone`, `Username`, `Password`  and `Address`.

The `Account` needs to be persisted in two databases. It needs to persisted into the `Application Database` (`Postgresql Server`) so that there can be a link between `Product` and `Account`. However, it also needs to be saved on the `389 Active Directory` server. This AD server holds all user records and their information.

I don’t want to duplicate all the data which is stored on the `Active Directory` server and save it to the `Application Server`. On the `Application Server` I want to save `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email` and the `ID`.

If a user chooses to change their `Account` details, this will then update the `Active Directory Server` and the fields stored in the `Application Server`.

E.G. A user logs on and wants to change their password. The password field is only stored in the `Directory server`. We use the `Novell LDAP` directory services library to access the information from the `Directory Server`.

In in our `Infrastructure Layer` we have a project where we implemented access to the AD server. So in the example above of changing password, we will only be talking to the AD server as there is no password saved in the `Application Server`.

Now the question is, in my domain to I create a model containing:

`ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Phone`, `Username`, `Password`, `Address`

Or

`ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`

There will be a screen in the UI where one can change all `Account` details.

Comment: are you using Active Directory or Novell LDAP? Either way - if you just store the user's AccountID, you can look up all the rest of the user details via a call to the DS.

Comment: It's a `389 Active Directory Server` and we are using the `Novel.Directory.LDap` third party library to communicate with it.

Comment: So not Active Directory at all, its a LDAP server. (AD is a Microsoft product). So just add ID to your domain and lookup the user as required, with caching you will get performance and single point of administration.

Comment: So basically do not create an `User` or `Account` mapping to the `Application database` when it comes to persistence mapping. Just use the `id` and look up the LDAP server, and cache it for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some more research in domain driven development.

`Bounded Contexts` seemed to help me solve this problem.

I started modeling out the system and not caring about the persistence, as you should do with DDD.

In the infrastructure level, I have separated out where data should be saved.

The data that is related to the `User` and `Organisation` for example, will be saved to `LDAP` where as all the other data will be saved to the application database.

We basically wrote a `Service` which the application services can use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are treading on dangerous ground here.

On one hand you have an LDAP authentication system which also has user name, and extra info in it.

On the other you have a domain concept of a product owner.

Its tempting to see the LDAP service as just a repository for product owners, but I dont think it really is. you will have all sorts of users in AD, only some of which will be product owners in your app and in the future you may have product owners in your app which are not in AD. (ie. someone leaves the company and is removed from AD?)

I would duplicate the data and have an extra AuthenticatedBy set of models to link product owners to your LDAP/AD system.

Comment: That is pretty much how we do it, there is a permissions system in place on top of it, and also each user gets assigned the ID of the Instance to which they got imported to. The idea is that all User information needs to be stored on LDAP and their ID's needs to be carried over and link up in the Application database so we have some record ow who owns the product as you say.